# bash : bad substitution while executing maven commad

Tags: bash, maven

I got the following error :

```
bash: -Dversion=${log4j.version}: bad substitution
```

while executing the following commad :

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=log4j -DartifactId=log4j -Dversion=${log4j.version} -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/user/Downloads/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

Any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash is trying to expand `${log4j.version}` and this is an invalid variable name. You have two approaches.

Without a `pom.xml` you need to provide a version by yourself:

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -DgroupId=log4j \
  -DartifactId=log4j \
  -Dversion=1.2.17 \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dfile=/home/user/Downloads/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

Use a `pom.xml` and optionally remove `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and/or `packaging` if you don't need to change them -- a valid `pom.xml` should have all of them:

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -Dfile=/home/user/Downloads/log4j-1.2.17.jar \
  -DpomFile=/home/user/Downloads/pom.xml
```

Comment: in fact I want the content of this variable which is defined in pom.xml

Comment: @foucha I changed the answer to better fit what you were expecting. Hth.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a backslash before the $:

```
     mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=log4j -DartifactId=log4j -Dversion=\${log4j.version} -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/user/Downloads/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```